# Align h4's in a Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css

```
Thanks for answering!
```

I would like to have the above HTML have all h4's be aligned together horizontally. The alignment is always off a little bit most of the time. Please help. I would like the h4 to be aligned next to each other despite the change in size.

Comment: could you provide a drawn sample for references?

Comment: You should enclose each topic in a div and use the grid or flex utilities

Comment: h4{text-align: center;}
a{text-align: inherit}

Comment: Do you actually need a grid? `class="d-flex"` on your container might suffice for your purpose. On a side note, `<h4>` elements are very likely not the right choice for your situation. Try to achieve a proper document outline for search engines and accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your HTML and wrap `<h4>` tags in columns.  like [this](https://codepen.io/amandeep1852/pen/GRQeZjv)

Comment: Please provide the code here instead of in a link.

Answer (score 0):

For class Col you have to give the Value for Separation based on column
**If you need 2 columns values be 6 for each**
If you need 3 columns values be 4 for each
**Total value is 12**
This give you horizontal position
based on the column spaces also get divided in bootstrap

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h4><a href="www.google.com">General research help</a></h4>
<p>Eliminate costs to students by using, adapting, or creating your own open educational resources.</p>
<h4><a href="www.google.com">3D &amp; maker technology</a></h4>
<p>See what software is available for students at the library, and request software we don’t have.</p>
<h4><a href="www.google.com">Citation Management</a></h4>
<p>Custom curated guides of library resources specific to course assignments.</p>
<h4><a href="www.google.com">Data &amp; GIS</a></h4>
<p>Interactive guides for learning everything from information literacy to critical use of sources to citation management.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<h4><a href="www.google.com">Archival &amp; Primary Sources</a></h4>
<p>Tools for managing citations, avoiding plagiarism, and more.</p>
<h4><a href="www.google.com">Scholarly Communication</a></h4>
<p>Articles, ebooks, video streaming, and more.</p>
<h4><a href="www.google.com">By educational field of study/Librarian by department</a></h4>
<p>Find and request materials for use in your course.</p>
<h4><a href="www.google.com">UX</a></h4>
<p>Get a personalized consultation session from one of our specialty librarians.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```